# Reduce cell margins in a table

Tags: tables

I have a table as shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
        \hline
        1 & 2  &  3\\ \hline
        \rot{\textbf{1st column}} & \rot{\textbf{2nd column}} & \rot{\textbf{3rd column}} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I would like the width of columns by reducing the padding. I have tried

```
\begin{tabular}{| p{0.1cm} | c | c |}
```

However, it only removes the white space in the right-hand side of the first column and leave the white space intact in the left-hand side of it.

Comment: `\setlength\tabcolsep{x pt}`. The default value is 6 pt (which makes a total of 12pt between two consecutive cells).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

To change the amount of vertical whitespace that LaTeX inserts to the left and right of every column, change the length parameter `\tabcolsep`. Its default value is `6pt`; change it via either `\setlength` or `\addtolength`. In the example below, the second table features a value of `1.5pt` for `\tabcolsep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
        \hline
        1 & 2  &  3\\ \hline
        \rot{\textbf{1st column}} & \rot{\textbf{2nd column\ }} & \rot{\textbf{3rd column}} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\qquad  % get some separation between the two tabulars
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt} % default value: 6pt
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
        \hline
        1 & 2  &  3\\ \hline
        \rot{\textbf{1st column}} & \rot{\textbf{2nd column\ }} & \rot{\textbf{3rd column}} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I adjust the separation of just some columns?

Comment: @Veridian - Insert `@{\hspace{<desired separation>}` in the desired location. E.g., write `\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{3em}c}` instead of just `\begin{tabular}{cc}`.

Comment: I think @MIco has a typo in that comment: It should be `\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{3em}}c}`, with one addition `}`.

Answer (score 20):

Is this what you looking for?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
      \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|@{\hskip3pt}c@{\hskip3pt}| c |@{\hskip3pt}c@{\hskip3pt}|}
            \hline
            1 & 2  &  3\\ \hline
            \rot{\textbf{1st column}} & \rot{\textbf{2nd column}} & \rot{\textbf{3rd column}} \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The `@{}` in place of insertion set `\tabcolsep` distance to zero. If you like to have in this place different space between adjacent columns, than you can locally determine it with  `@{<distance>}` where you select `<width>` according to your wish.

**Addendum**
Today, when the `tabularray` package (version 2021P)  is available, one may consider the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \setlength\rotheadsize{6em}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {ccc},
%             colsep = 6pt, % <--- default tabcolsep
             row{2}  = {cmd=\rotcell,font=\bfseries, rowsep=0pt}
            }
1           & 2             & 3             \\
1st column  & 2nd column    & 3rd column    \\
\end{tblr}
\qquad
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {ccc},
             colsep  = 2pt, % <--- tabcolsep
             row{2}  = {cmd=\rotcell,font=\bfseries, rowsep=0pt}
            }
1           & 2             & 3             \\
1st column  & 2nd column    & 3rd column    \\
\end{tblr}
\qquad
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {ccc},
             colsep  = 0pt, % <--- tabcolsep
             row{2}  = {cmd=\rotcell,font=\bfseries, rowsep=0pt}
            }
1           & 2             & 3             \\
1st column  & 2nd column    & 3rd column    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]