# How to have this input Form Field on many lines?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, forms

I want to have `\q{}` many lines, while it is designed for one line now. 
For example, take value from 2 to the maximum amount of lines per frame.
Code based on Christian's thread answer [Creating fillable PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/creating-fillable-pdfs/14845?noredirect=1#comment957973_14845).

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14845/13173
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14845/13173
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 

    \newdimen\longline
    \longline=\textwidth\advance\longline-4cm

    \def\LayoutTextField#1#2{#2} % override default in hyperref

    \def\lbl#1{\hbox to 4cm{#1\dotfill\strut}}%
    \def\labelline#1#2{\lbl{#1}\vbox{\hbox{\TextField[name=#1,width=#2,bordercolor=white]{\null}}\kern2pt\hrule}} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374712/13173

    \def\q#1{\hbox to \hsize{\labelline{#1}{\longline}}\vskip1.4ex}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{Form}
    \q{Merkki:} % TODO have here many lines
%   \q{}
%   \q{}
  \end{Form}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output in Fig. 1

Fig. 1 Output with only one line

[image]

Expected output: to have many lines (etc 3) for the input, and show the input on another page

### Testing UlrikeFisher's proposal in one environment

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

%\usepackage[margin=1pt]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry % Beamer loads geometry already!

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387474/13173
\usepackage{xparse,calc}
\usepackage{eforms}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Henkil\"{o}tiedot}
 % #Henkilotiedot https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387474/13173
 \medskip
 \textField[
    \Ff\FfMultiline
    \Ff\FfDoNotSpellCheck
           ]
  {myinput}{\dimexpr\linewidth-10ex}{5\baselineskip}
\end{frame}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385265/13173
\pdfpagewidth 21cm
\pdfpageheight 29.7cm

%% #Henkilotiedot
 \textField[
    \Ff\FfMultiline
    \Ff\FfDoNotSpellCheck
    \Ff\FfReadOnly
    \AA{\AACalculate{event.value=getField("myinput").value;}}
           ]
  {myoutput}{\dimexpr\linewidth-10ex}{5\baselineskip}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385438/13173
\newcommand*{\TableA}{%
%  \textcolor{gray}{\rule{.5\linewidth}{10cm}}%
    \begin{table}[hpt]
        \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt} % default value: 6pt % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201117/13173

        \begin{tabular}{|p{.2cm}|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|p{.2cm}|}
        \hline
        \rot{{\tiny\textbf{Avain muuttuja}}} 
        & \textbf{V2} & \textbf{V1} & \textbf{V0} 
            & \textbf{TESTI Muuttujat} 
            & \textbf{P1} & \textbf{P2} & \textbf{P3} 
            & \rot{{\tiny\textbf{Kriittinen muuttuja}}} \\ \hline
         &  &  &  & 1. Sosiaaliset taidot &  &  & & \\ \hline
         &  &  &  & 2. Ihmissuhteet (TS: K/E)* &  &  & & \\ \hline
         &  &  &  & 3. Ammatillinen arvio &  &  & & \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
}
\newcommand*{\TableB}{%
  \textcolor{red}{\rule{.5\linewidth}{3cm}}%
}
\newcommand*{\TableC}{%
  \textcolor{green}{\rule{.5\linewidth}{3cm}}%
}
\newcommand*{\TableD}{%
  \textcolor{blue}{\rule{.5\linewidth}{3cm}}%
}


% Show summary here from Page 1 and 2
\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols
\section{Summary}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \vskip 1.5cm
    \hspace*{-1.7cm}% to leave 1.0 cm margin
\begin{minipage}{19cm}
    \begin{center}
    TESTI
    \end{center}


    % Pisteytyskohta https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385438/13173
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \sbox0{\TableA}%
        \noindent
        \vtop{%
          \kern0pt % Align at the top
          \copy0 %
        }%
        \kern-.2pt %
        \vrule
        \kern-.2pt %
        \vtop to \dimexpr\ht0+\dp0{%
          \kern0pt % Align at the top
          \hbox{\TableB}%
          \vfill
          \hbox{\TableC}%
          \vfill
          \hbox{\TableD}%
        }
    \end{adjustbox}

\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

% these below eventually are not needed, if this is the last slide of your document
\makeatletter
\pdfpagewidth \beamer@paperwidth
\pdfpageheight \beamer@paperheight
\makeatother
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Fig. 2 Page setting is affected by the environment

[image]

OS: Debian 9
TeXLive: 2017
Acrotex installation: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387594/16920)

Comment: In trying to answer this, I realise it isn't really clear what you want, even though I initially thought it was :(.

Comment: I've edited my answer below for a case in which the form fields are multi-line. The single-line case works as desired, I'm told. I assume the multi-line case will also, but it is currently awaiting testing. (None of this works in Okular and I don't have access to Adobe Reader to test myself right now.)

Comment: I guess there's a question about where you need it to work. I need forms I can produce on Linux, but I only need them to work on Windows, so stuff which works OK in Adobe Reader is fine. But the forms stuff is not supported properly by any PDF viewer I'm familiar with for Linux. (If you know one which does support it properly, please let me know!)

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit unclear what you mean with many lines. But in case that you want a multiline text field, here an example with eforms. To get the value to the output page you can either use the same field name (but then you can't give them different "readonly" values), or use javascript (this needs a pdf viewer that can handle it):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse,calc}
\usepackage{eforms}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{frame}{Input}
 Question:  Say something about ....

 \medskip

 \textField[
    \Ff\FfMultiline
    \Ff\FfDoNotSpellCheck
           ]
  {myinput}{\dimexpr\linewidth-10ex}{5\baselineskip}

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Output}


 \textField[
    \Ff\FfMultiline
    \Ff\FfDoNotSpellCheck
    \Ff\FfReadOnly
    \AA{\AACalculate{event.value=getField("myinput").value;}}
           ]
  {myoutput}{\dimexpr\linewidth-10ex}{5\baselineskip}

\end{frame}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Create a small testtexmfhome.tex with some HELLO WORLD in it. Move is to a new folder in `insert-your-texmfhome-here/tex/latex/myfiles`  (get texmfhome with `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`) . Test in a document with `\input{testtexmfhome}` if is it found. If it works copy the files for acrotex there too.

Comment: I am trying to integrate your proposal in the environment with unique page setting unsuccessfully. Can you please see the body? How can you encapsulate the new textfield better?

Comment: I have no idea what you are actually trying to achieve. Why are you changing the page size? And why this complicated code for the tabulars?

Comment: Yes, I am changing the pagesize there. The complicated code with tabularx is for the presentation target there only. The aim is carry the text field info to the last presentation page of different page format.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot test this without Adobe Reader (or another compliant PDF viewer). However, this should work based on the usual behaviour. Moreover, comments say this does work as expected, even with the command wrapper used here.

Basically, if you give two text fields the same `name`, then filling in one populates both. I know this because I never want this behaviour and I have sometimes caused it accidentally, only to discover in class than I cannot fill out two different text fields with different content. (When I get to the second slide with a field of the same name, the field is pre-populated with an earlier answer. I can delete it and write a new answer, but that erases what I've input on the earlier slide.)

However, Okular does not appear to respect this behaviour, so I can't check that wrapping this in a macro works correctly. (Adobe crashes on Linux before you have time to blink. Well, first it takes a few hours to start. Then it freezes. Then it crashes before you have time to blink. Generally. It is not as predictable as one might like.)

Here's my original answer for the multiple single-line fields case. (See below for a multiple multi-line fields case.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse,calc}
\makeatletter
\newlength\textinput@labelwd
\newlength\textinput@fieldwd
\newlength\textinput@ht
\setlength\textinput@labelwd{40mm}
\setlength\textinput@fieldwd{\textwidth-40mm}
\setlength\textinput@ht{12pt}
\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{%
  \makebox[\textinput@labelwd]{\strut #1: \dotfill{} }#2%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\textinput{ s o +m }{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{\edef\textinput@tempa{#2}}{\edef\textinput@tempa{#3}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\edef\textinput@tempb{true}}{\def\textinput@tempb{false}}%
  \TextField[charsize={10pt},multiline=false,height=\textinput@ht,width={\textinput@fieldwd},name={\textinput@tempa},bordercolor={1 1 1},readonly=\textinput@tempb]{#3}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
  \begin{frame}{Input}
  \textinput{Merkki}

  \textinput[qna]{Qn.~A}

  \textinput[qnb]{Qn.~B}

  \textinput[merkki2]{Merkki}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Output}
  \textinput{Merkki}

  \textinput[qna]{Qn.~A}

  \textinput[qnb]{Qn.~B}

  \textinput[merkki2]{Merkki}
\end{frame}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Note that it probably matters that the frames occur in the same `Form`. However, I've never tried using `Form` inside a `frame` so I can't be sure of this. (I just always have `\begin{document}\begin{Form} ... \end{Form}\end{document}` in Beamer presentations.)

Here's an uninformative screenshot from Okular:

[image: uninformative screenshot]

## EDIT

Here's a multiple multi-line fields case, which is apparently what's wanted here.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse,calc,xcoffins}
\makeatletter
\newlength\textinput@labelwd
\newlength\textinput@fieldwd
\newlength\textinput@ht
\setlength\textinput@labelwd{40mm}
\setlength\textinput@fieldwd{\textwidth-40mm}
\setlength\textinput@ht{15mm}
\NewCoffin\textinputcoffin
\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{%
  \SetVerticalCoffin\textinputcoffin{\textinput@labelwd}{%
    \strut #1: \dotfill{} %
  }%
  \TypesetCoffin\textinputcoffin[t,l](0pt,\textinput@ht)#2%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\textinput{ s o +m }{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{\edef\textinput@tempa{#2}}{\edef\textinput@tempa{#3}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\edef\textinput@tempb{true}}{\def\textinput@tempb{false}}%
  \TextField[charsize={10pt},multiline=true,height=\textinput@ht,width={\textinput@fieldwd},name={\textinput@tempa},bordercolor={1 1 1},readonly=\textinput@tempb]{#3}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
  \begin{frame}{Input}
  \textinput{Merkki}

  \textinput[qna]{Qn.~A}

  \textinput[qnb]{Qn.~B}

  \textinput[merkki2]{Merkki}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Output}
  \textinput{Merkki}

  \textinput[qna]{Qn.~A}

  \textinput[qnb]{Qn.~B}

  \textinput[merkki2]{Merkki}
\end{frame}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

And an equally uninformative screenshot from Okular again:

[image: another uninformative screenshot]

Note that Okular does show the fields, but not in screenshots.

Comment: do you mean to test it on debian 9? And is there a reason to try on 2017 version? or my 2016 is ok to test it?

Comment: @koleygr I think you need Windows or Mac. Unless you can find a viewer which works on Linux. (In that case, please let me know!)

Comment: tested in windows 10 last adobe and it works fine... I just had some font issues (probably missed from my system)

Comment: @koleygr I've deleted my later comments.

Comment: @koleygr Please see edit above re. multi-line fields case. (I show multiple multi-line fields, but you can obviously use just one. Simply change the height setting accordingly.)

Comment: do you want to test your updated pdf? and if so, What do I have to test? If the line break is copied in second frame as is in first? Or what?

Comment: @koleygr Does entering information in the first page populate the corresponding box on the second page? Thanks for testing :-).

Comment: Tested and it is ok... But if that maters to you... output is an input too... (I suppose you already know if you write in output frame it is copied in input too)... Also adding more rows shown as a "+" sign on the lower right corner and allows you to "navigate" in the rows with a left sidebar if area is selected. Tested on adobe reader dc 2017.012.20095

Comment: @koleygr Thanks. So the `readonly` doesn't work even in Adobe's Reader. Interesting. Thanks very much for testing. (I don't know the `readonly` can work - I've never used it before. I only knew that naming the fields has this effect because I've done it by accident. It doesn't show on my machine in Okular, but then trouble when I use the slides in class on Windows.)

Comment: Why do you use the readonly?  I'm not sure that I understand its purpose.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because I thought it did something it doesn't, clearly. I wanted to have the output field with readonly true and the input with readonly false.

Comment: no this doesn't work. Such "twin"-fields share also most of their features (and normally the settings of the first field win).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As I said, the testing above showed it doesn't work.

Comment: Link to related question (regarding `name=` cannot duplicate): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73133/is-this-a-hyperref-forms-bug